# openplotter pi3 800x480 screen cut off

Tags: screen

Hi I Have a Pi 3 running openplotter (http://sailoog.com/en/openplotter) and a 7" 800x480 touch screen.  the desktop displays top to bottom but only about 80% from left to right.  BUT the tough screen thinks the desktop is the whole screen (i.e. if it tap top left it is in the right place but if I tap off the desktop top right it puts the curser on the edge of the desktop.  I have tried disabling overscan but no good.  [image: see photo]  The screen is small to begin with I want to be able to use the whole thing!

Comment: What make and model of screen is that ? Is the screen connected by hdmi (for image) and usb (for touch) ?

Comment: The screen is:https://raspberry.piaustralia.com.au/7-inch-lcd-hdmi-touch-screen-display-tft-for-raspb

Comment: Yes on HDMI and USB

Comment: Also FYI I tried it on Raspbian NOOBS_v2_3_0.  and it did the same thing only the resolution was worse almost unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the following to /boot/config.txt should correct the visual screen size :

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

Comment: @Electroviolin If this comment solved your problem be sure to mark the answer as right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Added the following to /boot/config.txt should correct the visual screen size :

hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0

Comment: Chris, friend, you misunderstood how Stack Exchange works ;) You must accept his @CoderMike's answer and delete the one you just posted